# jQuery Document Ready Function Syntax with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, api

I am trying to add the google geocode service to a webpage and am having some JavaScript trouble. When I add the below code without jQuery, I receive the null reference error, but can still occasionally get the service to work. Based on what I'm reading, it is the JS running before the element has loaded and I can wrap this JS into a jQuery function to resolve the issue. However, when I add my code as below, this is error is still popping up and I cannot get the service to run at all. Is there something incorrect in my jQuery syntax? I am very new to JS. Thanks.

**"JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'addListener' of undefined or null reference"**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        function initialize() {
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('PostalCodeID'));
            google.maps.evenet.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                var places = autocomplete.getplace();
                var location = "<b>Location:</b>" + places.formatted_address + "<br/>";
                location += "<b>Latitude:</b>" + places.geometry.location.A + "<br/>";
                location += "<b>Longitude:</b>" + places.geometry.location.F + "<br/>";
                document.getElementById('lblresult').innerHTML = location
            });
        };
        });

</script>
```

Comment: I don't think you need to install a "load" listener if you're putting the code inside a "ready" handler (or vice-versa). You only need to do one.

Comment: Also it should be `google.maps.event` not `evenet`. That's what the error is telling you.

Comment: I believe I need it to load the service. When I comment it out and run the code, it doesn't look like the service is available. I say that because when it is not commented out, the textbox displays 'Please enter a location'. I made an update that seems to be getting rid of the JS runtime error, but now the service is not returning addresses. Almost as if I need to add an event. Thank you for the response.

Comment: The "load" listener you're adding via the Google API should be all you need; that causes the "initialize" code to run only when the whole DOM is ready. If you're getting an error because an element can't be found, that probably means the element really isn't on the page. Without seeing other parts of your code (like, that element in particular) and details about how the page is built, it's hard to say what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As Pointy "pointed out" (sorry, couldn't help myself), you are using both an onLoad and an onReady handler.  Either one (but certainly the onReady) would handle any sort of "page hasn't loaded its contents yet" issues.  But, despite having both, you are still getting errors.

One likely culprit (also pointed out by Pounty) is your misspelling of `event` as `evenet`.  If you still get errors after fixing that then you likely have some other element which is missing when your code triggers.  The most likely culprit I see for that is your element with an ID "PostalCodeID".

There are also things you can do to  help narrow down the problem.  For instance, the stack trace of your error should include a pointer to a line of your code; if you look at which line that is it should help to determine what you're trying to do that the browser doesn't think is possible.

Once you find the line that is causing the problem, you can add a `debugger` statement just before it and then use your browser's debugger to see what's going on.  You can also run code like `document.getElementById('PostalCodeID')` to confirm that the element really is/isn't on the page at that point in time.